# pass checkbox value to controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How do I pass a value from my checkbox (view) to the controller?

```
<div className="row">
    <div class="filters-container col-sm-3">
        <h5 class="navbar navbar-dark bg-info">Brands</h5>

        <p>Apple</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filter" id="AppleFilter" value="true" name="Filters"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
public class ProductController : DaoController<ProductDao, Product>
{
    [HttpGet]
    public override IActionResult Get()
    {
        return InnerGet();
    }

    [HttpGet("{value}")]
    public IActionResult Search(string value)
    {
        var daoManager = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<DaoManager>();
        List<Product> products = daoManager.ProductDao.SearchProduct(value);
        return Ok(products);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Filter(string responsables, bool checkResp = false)
    {
        ///????
    }
```

I dont know what to put in the view and controller to pass the values.

Comment: your checkbox have to be a child element of some form. then the checked-state will be one of your form variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should introduce a ViewModel. A simple way to send the values is to POST this ViewModel to your controller action.

```
public class FilterViewModel {

   [DisplayName("Apple")]
   public bool DoApplyAppleFilter { get; set; }
}
```

Tell the View `Filter.cshtml` to use this ViewModel:

```
@model FilterViewModel 

@* this <form> will be posted to the "Filter" action in the "ProductController" *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ym-form"})) {

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DoApplyAppleFilter)    @* renders <label> with the given DisplayName for the checkbox *@
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DoApplyAppleFilter) @* renders <input type="checkbox"> *@

    <button type="submit">Apply filter</button>
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Filter(FilterViewModel viewModel) {

   bool isChecked = viewModel.DoApplyAppleFilter;
   // ...
}
```

Instead of a submit `<button>`, you can also use AJAX to POST the `<form>`, or extract the values and use a GET request.